# Why ListBoxItems does not get all the available space?

Tags: .net, wpf, layout, listbox, windows-phone-8

Take this simple example:

```
    <Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate  >
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="FIRST TEXT" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="SECOND TEXT"  />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        a
        a
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

As far as I know this should show the FIRST TEXT on the left half of the application screen and the SECOND TEXT on the right half.

Instead of this the two texts are one after the other. as if the grid thought that all the available space is the one used by the text. Maybe I need to change something on the Listbox panel?

EDIT: I have tried this:

```
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And even when it Works it breaked the selected feature of the listboxitem :(

By the way, I'm working on Windows pone 8

Answer (score 3):

Use `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` applied to the ListBox. See the solution listed below. *Note*: I have included separate `Background="AntiqueWhite"` and `Background="Aqua"` for your convenience, so you can see the actual size of both TextBlocks.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="FIRST TEXT" Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="SECOND TEXT"  Background="Aqua"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        a
        a
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This does not make any difference :(

Comment: I have included the explanation and the actual code snippet in my answer. It's been tested in VS 2010 and works fine. Rgds,

Comment: Thanks, folks (in particular, @Xcalibur37), I appreciate! Rgds,

Comment: Thanks. Your solution Works on a Pc application but it does not on a WP8 App. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SoMoS: Thanks for this clarification. The solution I've posted has been tested in VS2010 on PC running Win7. Rgds,